# How to check if an HTML5 validation was triggered using PhantomJS?

Tags: testing, ember.js, phantomjs

I am testing my Ember app (Ember 1.6) using PhantomJS(ver. 2.1.1). I want to assert that an HTML5 validation is triggered for invalid input. Here is my test:

```
fillIn('#MyInputField', 'some invalid data');
click('#MyButton');

andThen(function() {
    strictEqual(find('#MyInputField:invalid').length, 1, 'Expected HTML 5 validation triggered!');
});
```

This works fine when I test it using Karma running in a browser. But when testing in PhantomJS, this fails.

I have made screenshot, and according to that image, there is no HTML5 validation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to upgrade Phantom? The default Phantom installed by many CI services (Phantom 1.9) is missing some ES6 features and may be missing what you need too.

Comment: I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1 which  is pretty new.